# Explain sorting in ASP.NET Dynamic Data

Tags: .net, asp.net, dynamic-data

Can anyone explain what the Dynamic Data team was thinking when they designed grid sorting in Dynamic Data scaffolded tables?  Sorting defaults to using all columns, in the order the appear in the model, often arbitrary very counter-productive.

We've just had a run in with the 'out-of-the-box' sorting, and solved it with a simple SortExpression attribute on MetaTables.  Another, even simpler solution would have been for them to avoid any sorting, allowing the DB to provide a default order based on clustered index.

Is this another attack of the architecture astronaughts?

Comment: i like this essentially because you allude to the solution (SortExpresion) while ranting about it. cheers.

Comment: @Irwin, the SortExpression solution is one we created to solve the problem, not what I'm ranting about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [DisplayColumn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.displaycolumnattribute.aspx) attribute:

```
[DisplayColumn("Name", "DOrder", false)]
public partial class Customer { }
```

allows default sorting specified on Metadata(above I am sorting customers ascending on a column called DOrder).

Or, you can easily add any sort parameters to the grid's datasource using

> GridDataSource.OrderByParameters()

.